# Написать код при помощи оператора цикла while, do while

Tags: c++

Написать код при помощи оператора цикла while, do while (**без применения массивов и прямой адресации курсора**) для распечатки на экране монитора указанного в варианте набора символов. Результат который должен получится на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример кода:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            cout << char('A' + ((i == j) ? 0 : (i > j) ? 4 - j : j)) << ' ';
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Знаете, имея цикл `for`, не написать цикл `while` - это уже за гранью, так сказать... В любом учебнике по языку есть, как эквивалентно записать один цикл через другой!

Comment: А вопрос в чем?

Comment: нужен код который будет давать тот же результат но уже с применением другого оператора цикла

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Рискну, невзирая на возможное недовольство Harry :) Но я не буду решать вашу проблему, а только напишу, что

цикл

```
for(a; b; c) d;
```

эквивалентен

```
a; while(b) { d; c; }
```

Comment: Я только начал учить, можно по подробнее с примером если не затруднит

Comment: А вот это уже нет. Тут @Harry прав. Я просто изложил материал из учебника. Вы должны понять и сделать сами, иначе так и останетесь неумейкой...